# JavaFx FileChooser without Stage

Tags: java, javafx, jfilechooser, stage, filechooser

I am in the process of learnig JavaFx, and I encountered a problem. I was trying to use FileChooser from JavaFx the way I was used to working with JFileChooser from Swing-in the main() method. However I found out that I need a Window object. I've tried searching for a workaround, but I found none. I've also tried null (as you do in JFileChooser) and new Stage(), so those are off the table. I was trying to mimic the JFileChooser.showOpenDialog(). Is there any reasonable way to make it work?

Answer (score 5):

The `main` method is not executed on the FX Application Thread, so you can't show a `FileChooser` from it. (You can't really do that in Swing either, unless you are using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`.)

In JavaFX, the responsibility for starting the application is in the `start()` method, which is executed on the FX Application Thread. (In many runtime environments, you don't even need a `main` method in JavaFX applications.)

Just show the file chooser from the start method, where you have access to the `primaryStage` (or can just pass `null`, if you like):

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        FileChooser configFileChooser = new FileChooser();
        File configFile = configFileChooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);

        // ... parse file and create UI, etc...

        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: What I can do in Swing is JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
  if(jfc.showOpenDialog(null)==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
   mapFile=jfc.getSelectedFile();
  } anywhere in code(including main())

Comment: Just because you can do it, and it happens to run on your particular platform, doesn't make it correct. That code in Swing is incorrect: it shows a `JFileChooser` from a thread that is not the event dispatch thread. There is no guarantee of it working on other platforms or under future releases. This is a very common error, so JavaFX goes to the trouble of checking the threading (in many cases) and throwing exceptions if it is incorrect.

Comment: never even knew it was wrong....... is it fine in listeners (most common use for me)?

Comment: Sure, because listeners are executed on the event dispatch thread (they are executed as part of the process of dispatching events). If you read the [documentation for any swing class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) it says "**Warning:** Swing is not thread safe. For more information see [Swing's Threading Policy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading)", and the link fully describes all the restrictions.